# Transition of view controllers - from left to right

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, transition

I am NOT using navigation controller, and I am using storyboards.

I have to make a transition from 1 view controller to other, for which I am using segue.

Now I set the segue style to Custom, and in the corresponding class, I override the `perform` method.

```
-(void)perform
{
    UIViewController *sourceViewController = [self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *destinationViewController = [self destinationViewController];

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.25;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;

    [sourceViewController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];animated:NO];
    [sourceViewController presentViewController:destinationViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

But there is also a property of the destination view controller `modalTransitionStyle`.

So Right now, the source VC goes from left to right as if it is being pushed, but I want to show that it is being pushed by the destination view controller. Instead, the destination VC does a 'Cover Vertical' by default, and there are only four options available for the `modalTransitionStyle` property, none of which is working for me.

I think to make it work, this animation should be added to some superview layer, a superview from which both view controllers have been presented. But there is no such superview..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually you would give a storyboardId to the destinationController and call it like this from the sourceViewController:

```
//push next view
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
YourViewControllerClass *destVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryboardID"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:destVC animated:YES];
```

Optionally, you can do it manually like this:

```
    // Get the views.
    UIView * fromView = sourceViewController.view;
    UIView * toView = destinationViewController.view;

    // Get the size of the view area.
    CGRect viewSize = fromView.frame;

    // Add the toView to the fromView
    [fromView.superview addSubview:toView];

    // Position it off screen.
    toView.frame = CGRectMake( 320 , viewSize.origin.y, 320, viewSize.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:
     ^{
         // Animate the views on and off the screen. This will appear to slide.
         fromView.frame =CGRectMake( -320 , viewSize.origin.y, 320, viewSize.size.height);
         toView.frame =CGRectMake(0, viewSize.origin.y, 320, viewSize.size.height);
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         if (finished)
         {
             // Remove the old view from its parent.
             [fromView removeFromSuperview];

             //I use it to have navigationnBar and TabBar at the same time
             //self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = indexPath.row+1;
         }
     }];
```

** **EDIT** **

Inverse function (similar to the back button in the navigation controller):

```
// Get the views.
UIView * fromView = fromViewController.view;
UIView * toView = destViewController.view;

// Get the size of the view area.
CGRect viewSize = fromView.frame;

// Add the to view to the tab bar view.
[fromView.superview addSubview:toView];

// Position it off screen.
toView.frame = CGRectMake( -320 , viewSize.origin.y, 320, viewSize.size.height);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:
 ^{
     // Animate the views on and off the screen. This will appear to slide.
     fromView.frame =CGRectMake( 320 , viewSize.origin.y, 320, viewSize.size.height);
     toView.frame =CGRectMake(0, viewSize.origin.y, 320, viewSize.size.height);
 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     if (finished)
     {
         // Remove the old view from the tabbar view.
         [fromView removeFromSuperview];
     }
 }];
```

Comment: I am not using navigation controller. And would the 2nd metho of yours be same as 'presenting' a view? I mean would it call `viewWillAppear` and other such methods? And would I be able to 'dismiss' the view or would I be doing something similar to remove the view?

Comment: Or can you tell me some steps using which I can convert my app to use a navigation controller? I have VC1, which can present VC2 or VC3. VC2 and VC3 have to relation to each other.

Comment: @neeraj the 2nd method would append the second view at the right side, slide to the right until only that view is visible, then dismiss the first view. All corresponding methods, such as `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` will be called as usual. If by dismiss you mean something like the behavior generated by `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`, you can do it by calling a function that does the same but in an inverted order (attaching the new view to the left and slide to the left).

Comment: @neeraj I have added an edit to the answer to emulate the sliding back

Comment: Thanks a lot simpleBob. But I think this might require some significant changes in the app!

Comment: i want animation for Transition of view controllers - from top to bottom and bottom to top then what are the changes mainly

Comment: @Arunakumari Where the frames are set, make the changes in `origin.y` and `size.height` instead, and set `origin.x` and `size.width` to that of the view.

Comment: // Position it off screen.
        toView.frame = CGRectMake(viewSize.origin.x,-580 ,580,viewSize.size.width);
        
      
             fromView.frame = CGRectMake(viewSize.origin.x,580,580,viewSize.size.width);
             toView.frame =CGRectMake(viewSize.origin.x,0,580,viewSize.size.width);
       
i chaged the code like above but not getting exact animation.please help me

Comment: @Arunakumari you set the width & height wrong. Try: `toView.frame = CGRectMake(viewSize.origin.x,-580 ,viewSize.size.width, 580);` `fromView.frame = CGRectMake(viewSize.origin.x,580,viewSize.size.width, 580);` `toView.frame =CGRectMake(viewSize.origin.x,0,viewSize.size.width, 580);`

Answer (score 1):

All of the ViewControllers in my app inherit from `MyViewController` which, in addition to some other default behaviours, has this property:

```
@property(readwrite, nonatomic) BOOL slideFromSide;
```

And this code:

```
- (void) presentViewController: (UIViewController*) vc animated: (BOOL) flag completion: (void (^)(void)) completion
{
    BOOL slideIn = NO;
    if ([vc isKindOfClass: [MyViewController class]])
    {
        MyViewController *svc = (MyViewController*) vc;
        slideIn = svc.slideFromSide;
    }

    if (slideIn)
    {
        [self addChildViewController: vc];
        [self.view addSubview: vc.view];

        CGRect frame = vc.view.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width;
        vc.view.frame = frame;

        frame.origin.x = 0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.33
                         animations: ^{
                             vc.view.frame = frame;
                         }
         ];
    }
    else
    {
        [super presentViewController: vc animated: flag completion: completion];
    }
}


- (IBAction) backAction: (id) sender
{
    if (_slideFromSide)
    {
        CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width;
        [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.33
                         animations: ^{
                             self.view.frame = frame;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             [self removeFromParentViewController];
                         }
         ];
    }
    else
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
    }
}
```

Then, in the ViewControllers where I want to slide-in, I have:

```
- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName: nibNameOrNil bundle: nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
        self.slideFromSide = YES;
        // Whatever else you want to do
    }

    return self;
}
```

Calling a new ViewController is just like normal:

```
WhateverViewController *vc = [WhateverViewController alloc] initWithNibName: nil bundle: nil];
[self presentViewController: vc animated: YES completion: nil];
```