# emulate iOS7 controller push animation

Tags: iphone, ios7, pushviewcontroller

Until now I have been using the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631653/transition-of-view-controllers-from-left-to-right/15632260#15632260) to simulate pushing a view. But now the view pushing animation changed. Does anyone have code to simulate the new animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way to simulate it, which is pretty pretty close to the original.

You have to add [MTAnimation](https://github.com/mysterioustrousers/MTAnimation) (which is needed for the exponential ease out). This library will need `QuartzCore`, so you will have to add it to your "linked libraries" in "build phases" within project settings if it isn't already added.

And here is the code:

**push controller animation**

```
// Get the views
UIView * fromView = sourceViewController.view;
UIView * toView = destinationViewController.view;
UIView *darkenView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:fromView.frame];
[darkenView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:255 blue:255 alpha:0]];
[fromView addSubview:darkenView];

// Get the size of the view area.
CGRect viewSize = fromView.frame;

// Add the new view to the old view.
[fromView.superview addSubview:toView];

// Position the new view outside of the screen
toView.frame = CGRectMake( viewSize.size.width , viewSize.origin.y, viewSize.size.width, viewSize.size.height);
[UIView mt_animateViews:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fromView, toView, nil]
               duration:.55
         timingFunction:MTTimingFunctionEaseOutExpo
                options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent
             animations:
    ^{
        // Animate the replacing of the views 
        fromView.frame =CGRectMake( -(viewSize.size.width/3) , viewSize.origin.y, viewSize.size.width, viewSize.size.height);
        toView.frame =CGRectMake(0, viewSize.origin.y, viewSize.size.width, viewSize.size.height);
        [darkenView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:.1]];
    }
                 completion:
    ^{
        // Remove the old view 
        [darkenView removeFromSuperview];
        [fromView removeFromSuperview];
    }];
```

**pop controller animation (like with the back button)**

```
// Get the views.
UIView * fromView = sourceViewController.view;
UIView * toView = destinationViewController.view;

// Get the size of the view area.
CGRect viewSize = fromView.frame;

// Add the new view to the old view.
[fromView.superview insertSubview:toView belowSubview:fromView];

// Position the new view outside of the screen
toView.frame = CGRectMake( -(viewSize.size.width/3) , viewSize.origin.y, viewSize.size.width, viewSize.size.height);

UIView *darkenView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:toView.frame];
[darkenView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:.1]];
[toView addSubview:darkenView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent animations:
^{
         // Animate the replacing of the views 
         fromView.frame =CGRectMake(viewSize.size.width , viewSize.origin.y, viewSize.size.width, viewSize.size.height);
         toView.frame =CGRectMake(0, viewSize.origin.y, viewSize.size.width, viewSize.size.height);
         darkenView.frame = toView.frame;
         [darkenView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:255 blue:255 alpha:0]];
}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
    if (finished)
    {
        // Remove the old view 
        [fromView removeFromSuperview];
        [darkenView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}];
```